# Exception while reading from the Chronicle Map file

Tags: chronicle-map

I am using version 3.8.0 and I am getting following exception. I am using the ChronicleMap without much customization. I am currently prototyping to exhibit ChronicleMap as a viable option to share data between different JVM processes on the same box. I do not see any problem when I create an instance where I am putting stuff into the ChronicleMap. But, when, I try to use ChronicleMap mainly as a reader then I am seeing this exception everytime.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant net.openhft.chronicle.hash.serialization.impl.StopBitSizeMarshaller.{}
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.util.ObjectUtils.convertTo0(ObjectUtils.java:142)
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.util.ObjectUtils.convertTo(ObjectUtils.java:130)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.ValueIn.object(ValueIn.java:440)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.TextWire$TextValueIn.objectWithInferredType(TextWire.java:2482)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.TextWire$TextValueIn.typedMarshallable(TextWire.java:2290)
at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.VanillaChronicleHash.readMarshallableFields(VanillaChronicleHash.java:240)
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap.readMarshallableFields(VanillaChronicleMap.java:107)
at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.impl.VanillaChronicleHash.readMarshallable(VanillaChronicleHash.java:225)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.SerializationStrategies$1.readUsing(SerializationStrategies.java:22)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.TextWire$TextValueIn.marshallable(TextWire.java:2228)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.ValueIn.object(ValueIn.java:429)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.TextWire$TextValueIn.objectWithInferredType(TextWire.java:2482)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.TextWire$TextValueIn.typedMarshallable(TextWire.java:2290)
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.openWithExistingFile(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1598)
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createWithFile(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1444)
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.recoverPersistedTo(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1416)
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createOrRecoverPersistedTo(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely reason is wrong version of `chronicle-wire` dependency used. Chronicle Map 3.8.0 is proven to work with [`chronicle-bom:1.11.16`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.openhft%7Cchronicle-bom%7C1.11.16%7Cpom), which specifies Chronicle Wire version 1.3.6, but no other older or newer version of `chronicle-bom` or Chronicle Wire.

**Update.** The new [Chronicle Map 3.9.0](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/releases/tag/chronicle-map-3.9.0) version shouldn't have this issue regardless Chronicle Wire version used.

Comment: My value is a custom class in scala whose fields are Option for eg case class Person(name: Option[String], age:Option[Int]). Can such a structure make a difference? Today, I will try with Person class which doesn't take Option and see what happens and also, use the suggested version.

Comment: No, value type shouldn't make difference. Only Wire library version.

Comment: After using the v1.3.6 of chronicle-wire, I no more get this error. Now, I need to figure what version of chronicle-queue(CQ) will be compatible with this version of Chronicle-Map since CQ will also bring in the chronicle-wire dependency.